# Is it possible to set to unchanged a propery of an entity and don't affect to the rest of the entity?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I am using EF Core 3.0.0 and I would like to set to unchanged an propery of an entity.

I know that I can change the state of a whole entity, but I would like to know if it is possible to set the state of a property of an entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `IsModified` to `false` for the property you need.

```
dbContext.Entry(yourModel).Property(x => x.YourProperty).IsModified = false;
```